# How to find out how many variable variables there are and randomise?

Tags: php, variables

I've created a collection of variable variables using a foreach loop and I want to find out how many there are; and then select one with pseudo randomness.

Example code:

```
$count = 0;

foreach ($a as $key => $b) {

    $count++;
    $new_stuff["stuff" . $count] = $b;

            }

extract($new_stuff);
```

I can then echo out each stuff, like this:

```
echo $stuff1[0];
```

or...

`echo implode($stuff1);` (this one gives me double the result)

I want to find out how many $stuff variables there are* and then pick one with one with rand(). Is it somehow possible to construct a variable from two parts, like this pseudocode: $stuff = "stuff" and attaching, say, number 5 so that it becomes $stuff5?

*I can find out the number of elements that create the various $stuff variables by using this:

```
$shift = rand(0, count($a));
```

Comment: I really do not understand what you want to do. You want find out how many variables are named "stuff*"?

Comment: $a is retrieved from a database, so depending on how many $b there are, different stuff variables are created. If there are 10 elements in the database, there will be $stuff1, $stuff2, $stuff3...I want to find out how many such variations of $stuff are created.

Comment: @DanSebastian is there a reason need to extract it into a variable?  What is a sample of the array $a?  Why do you not just use `count($a)`?  Based on your loop, that will be the same as the number of "stuff" created.

Comment: $devon, the ultimate goal is to be able to select one of the variables randomly; and so I figured that if there was a way to know how many stuff variables there were, I could select one with rand(). But I'm open for better alternatives.

Comment: Why you can't use just `$selectRandom = $a[array_rand($a)]`?

Comment: btw [`array_rand($a, 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) could be enough if your keys are not numeric ...

Comment: Thx, Leggendario, I wasn't familiar with that function, that solved all my probs. Does the original question hold any merit? If not, I think I ought to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_rand is an option but rand() is not a very reliable random number generator.

Assuming your keys are numeric, it would be better to use mt_rand() with count().

```
$random = $a[ mt_rand(0, count($a)-1) ];
```